# Save file by button in python telebot

Tags: python, button, telebot

I have Keyboard type buttons, how do I make it so that when you click on the button, you can send a file and it is saved to a directory?
The bot does not accept files until the button is pressed, but after it has been pressed at least once, it accepts the file at any time, and I would like only after clicking

```
elif message.text == 'Send file': #button's name
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'put ur file')
            @bot.message_handler(content_types =['document'])
            def save_file(message):
                    try:
                        chat_id = message.chat.id
                        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
                        file_name, file_extenstion = os.path.splitext(file_info.file_path)
                        now = datetime.datetime.now()
                        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
                        src = 'archive/' + now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') + file_extenstion
                        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
                            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
                        bot.reply_to(message, "File saved")
                    except Exception as e:
                        bot.reply_to(message, e)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.